# Why does this write() operation just write a single line

Tags: c++, linux, file, csv, append

I have a small problem with my code in the following. I call it in my class from within a state machine `this->write_file(this->d_filename);`. The case in the loop gets hit a couple of times, however I only have one line of entries in the CSV file I want to produce.

I'm not sure why this is. I open the file with `this->open(filename)` in my write function. It returns the file-descriptor. The file is opened with O_TRUNK, and `if ((d_new_fp = fdopen(fd, d_is_binary ? "wba" : "w")) == NULL)`. While the aba refers to write, binary and append. Therefore I expect more than one line.

The fprintf statement writes my data. It also has a `\n`.

```
 fprintf(d_new_fp, "%s, %d %d\n", this->d_packet, this->d_lqi, this->d_lqi_sample_count);
```

I simply can't figure out why my file doesn't grow.

Best,
Marius

```
 inline bool
    cogra_ieee_802_15_4_sink::open(const char *filename)
    {
      gruel::scoped_lock guard(d_mutex); // hold mutex for duration of this function

      // we use the open system call to get access to the O_LARGEFILE flag.
      int fd;
      if ((fd = ::open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | OUR_O_LARGEFILE,
          0664)) < 0)
        {
          perror(filename);
          return false;
        }

      if (d_new_fp)
        { // if we've already got a new one open, close it
          fclose(d_new_fp);
          d_new_fp = 0;
        }

      if ((d_new_fp = fdopen(fd, d_is_binary ? "wba" : "w")) == NULL)
        {
          perror(filename);
          ::close(fd);
        }

      d_updated = true;
      return d_new_fp != 0;
    }

    inline void
    cogra_ieee_802_15_4_sink::close()
    {
      gruel::scoped_lock guard(d_mutex); // hold mutex for duration of this function

      if (d_new_fp)
        {
          fclose(d_new_fp);
          d_new_fp = 0;
        }
      d_updated = true;
    }

    inline void
    cogra_ieee_802_15_4_sink::write_file(const char* filename)
    {
      if (this->open(filename))
        {

          fprintf(d_new_fp, "%s, %d %d\n", this->d_packet, this->d_lqi,
              this->d_lqi_sample_count);
          if (true)
            {
              fprintf(stderr, "Writing file %x\n", this->d_packet);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to call cogra_ieee_802_15_4_sink::close() method  at the end of write_file().

Comment: `O_TRUNC` sets the size of the file to 0 bytes

Comment: Every time you call `cogra_ieee_802_15_4_sink::write_file` you open the file with `O_TRUNC`, truncating the file to zero length, then you write one line. And you are surprised you only get one line in the file?

Comment: jepp, seems I mixed up O_TRUNC and O_APPEND in my head this morning. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description for `O_TRUNC` from [man open](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open):

> If the file already exists and is a regular file and the open mode allows writing (i.e., is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) it will be truncated to length 0. If the file is a FIFO or terminal device file, the O_TRUNC flag is ignored. Otherwise the effect of O_TRUNC is unspecified.

The file is opened in each call to `write_file()`, removing anything that was previously written. Replace `O_TRUNC` with `O_APPEND`.